# show DEVISE authentication key (email Address ) during password reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I think this is a simple one,  I want to display the authentication key during a password reset.

First,  is there any problem with doing so?  Is there some kind of hole I'm opening up?  I control when a user is created and sent signup_instructions.  I only have about 500 users.  My system is one where in many cases, it is only used a few times a year,  and by only one or two employees at smallish companies , average 10 employees.  Some of the companies we service , rather than create multiple accounts for employees, share one or more accounts,  i.e. I create it for a specific person at the company, then they share the password with their assistant(s).  I use email addresses for authentication key.

Can you guess what's coming next?  This really happened!  User goes on vacation,  young assistant needs to log in, forgot the password,  but is savvy enough to click forgot password and reset it,  she reads bosses emails while boss is gone.  Boss returns from vacation, needs to log in, can't,  but isn't savvy enough to click forgot password and didn't bother to read her emails that came in while she was gone.  So she calls in a panic and pissed off,  'what's wrong, I can't log in!!!'.  Many of my users are like that, older, not real computer literate.

So I need to take extra steps to idiot proof resetting passwords,  which I'm thinking should include PROMINENT display of the email address they are about to reset,  plus wording to remind anyone who's 'sharing' an account to inform their co-workers if they reset.

I tried this in my devise/passwords/edit

```
<%= resource.email %>
```

The above code yields nothing!

Comment: Typically to reset a password the user should have to enter the email address of the account to reset.  Is this not the approach you are doing? You dont want people to be able to reset another users account.

Comment: Yes,  my reset password link requires that you enter the email address ,  it's pretty much the standard device/passwords/new.html.erb formatted to match my site design

Comment: That should be all you do then. No need to provide the user(or a potential intruder) any more information than that.  Sharing accounts is typically frowned upon but if they are doing that then your responsibility ends there.  You do not need to change anything, as if a user decides to share an account with their assistant and the assistant changes something, that is not your problem.

Comment: It's not the liability I'm worried about,  I just want to prevent IRATE phone calls.  This 'older un-savvy agent' with young assistants scenario is rather common in my world.

Answer (score -1):

You should never expose authentication data. That's why you never send them with GET but instead with POST. Do some research: how does gmail reset passwords? Another thing to remember, once you have done all that's reasonable, a user is responsible for safeguarding his personal information. If the secretary knows everything about the boss, then that's too bad -- unless they want you to use biometric to reset passwords.

Comment: Believe me,  I tried very hard to dissuade the user the first time I discovered the practice of sharing accounts.  No luck,  they insisted.  I had to have our lawyer add some verbiage to our contract that  specifically indemnifies us from the practice.  My users are a weird lot,  the difficult ones are those that have celebrities for clients,  they think it entitles them to special treatment.

Comment: BTW,  how am I exposing authentication data?  I'm not sure I understand the comment?

Comment: Your title. Did I misunderstand the title? Or rather what do you mean then by authentication key?

Comment: yea just the email address,  which is generically called the authentication key in devise,  in case anyone who was using devise and using a userid as their authentication key instead of email address

Comment: fixed title,  it was confusing, I thought just adding devise tag was enough, sorry